# How to do Order By with null at the end

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have a student table with a test date column and I want to create a query that will order by date
from the oldest first to new and that all the columns that have null in it will be the last

**what I need**

```
01/01/2020
15/02/2020
null
null
```

**what i get**

```
null
null
01/01/2020
15/02/2020
```

is it pussible do it without invoke 2 queries or add an additional column and use then order..

tnx

Comment: I found a great answer for that, orderby x.date.HasValue desanding, x.date

Answer (score 2):

You could order by a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN date_col IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, date_col;
```

This approach used a two level sort which puts all non null date records first, followed by null ones last.  Within each of those two groups, we sort ascending by date.

Comment: The resulting values of a case expression must be all the same type, so SQL will convert the 1 or zero to a date, which may give you an unexpected result.

Comment: @Sean ... um the only possible outputs from the `CASE` expression I used are 0 or 1.  Last time I checked they were both integers, so ...

Answer (score 0):

For sql server :

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
date datetime NULL
)


insert into Test (date)
values('2020-01-01'),
('2020-02-15'),
(NULL),
(NULL)


select * from Test
ORDER BY IIF(date IS NULL, 1, 0), date;
```

See the link : https://rextester.com/CXK25023

Answer (score -2):

Try replacing the null value with something more meaningful in your order by. So

`isnull(column1, '2100-01-01')`